# how to do event based serial port reading in c?

Tags: c++, c, windows

i want to read serial port when there is some data present i mean on the event when data arrives only then i will read serial port instead of continuously reading the port i have this code for continuous reading the port how can i make it event based.

thanx in advance.

```
while(1)
{
   bReadRC = ReadFile(m_hCom, &byte, 6, &iBytesRead, NULL);
   printf("Data Recieved Through Serial port and no. of Bytes Recieved is    %d",iBytesRead);
 }
```

Comment: Why do you find it so difficult to tag your questions with the operating system you are using?

Comment: Please use punctuation marks! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363479%28VS.85%29.aspx) you can use the `WaitCommEvent()` operation on your serial port handle.
Also, [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx) gives a nice introduction into the topic.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like WinAPI, and I'm not exactly an expert at that, but you should be able to set the port to *blocking mode*. This will cause the read call to block (wait on that line) until there's data available.